# How to get all rows from mysql database without while() loop to increase page load time?

Tags: php

Well, In my mysql database there are more than 3,000 rows exists. It's continuously growing. Now I'm using following query to show all data on html row `(tr)`. it's take few more seconds to show the all data.

Is there any way to show all data more quickly without using PHP `while` loop ? Please give me your advise/solution after check my all code. Thank You.

```
<?php
echo "<table width='540' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0' id='topresutl'>";
echo "<thead>";
   echo "<tr>";             
   echo "<td class='' valign='top' width='155'></td>";
   echo "<td class='' valign='top' width='110'></td>";                              
   echo "<td class='' valign='top' width='100'></td>";                              
   echo "<td class='' valign='top' width='95'></td>";                               
   echo "<td class='' valign='top' width='80'></td>";                               
   echo "</tr>";    
   echo "</thead>";
   echo "<tbody>";              

    while($res =  mysqli_fetch_array($get)){
        $cdid = (int) $res['cdid'];
        $family_name = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($res['family_name']));
        $given_name = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($res['given_name']));
        $work_phone = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($res['work_phone']));
        $mobile_phone = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($res['mobile_phone']));
        $email = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($res['email']));
        $email_private = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($res['email_private']));
        $cid = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($res['cid']));
        $department = stripslashes($res['department']);
        $title = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($res['title']));

        $getComapnyName =  mysqli_query($link, "SELECT company_name FROM company WHERE cid = '$cid' ");
        $resCompany =  mysqli_fetch_array($getComapnyName);
        $companyName =  $resCompany['company_name'];


        if (strlen($companyName) >= 15) {
            $companyName =  substr($companyName, 0, 14);
        }

        if (strlen($family_name) >= 10) {
            $family_name =  substr($family_name, 0,8);
            }
       if (strlen($given_name) >= 10) {
            $given_name =  substr($given_name, 0, 8);
           }
       if (strlen($department) >= 12) {
            $department =  substr($department, 0, 10);
           }
       if (strlen($title) >= 12) {
            $title =  substr($title, 0, 10);
            }


   echo "<tr onclick='getDetails($cdid), showthirdbox($cdid), visited(this);'>";                                
   echo "<td class='' valign='top' align='left' width='20'>$companyName</td>";
   echo "<td class='' valign='top'>$family_name</td>";
   echo "<td class='' valign='top'>$given_name</td>";
   echo "<td class='' valign='top'>$department</td>";
   echo "<td class='' valign='top'>$title</td>";

   echo "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
   }
echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";    
?>
```

Comment: What makes you think that the `while` loop is the problem? Sending 3000 rows of data to a browser is going to take a while. Profile your code and find the bottleneck before you try to optimise. FWIW a loop is the only way to get all the data; get rid of all those `stripslashes` too.

Comment: I wan to know which loop performance is better in this situation.

Comment: and use prepared statement if you really want to get rid of sql injection vulnerability

Comment: Thank You. obi NullPoiиteя kenobi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you should do is stop running a query to get company name inside your while loop. You need to use a JOIN to select the company name from the company table with your main query.

Since you didn't include your main query, I can't write it for you. But it will look something like this (I'm assuming your main table is named "employees"):

```
SELECT e.*, c.company_name 
FROM employees AS e 
LEFT JOIN company AS c ON e.cid = c.id
```

You might want to Google for join syntax to learn more about using joins or to adapt it to your exact usage.

Chances are good this will significantly improve your render time.

If it's still too slow then I would ask how many records you're trying to show on the screen at one time. If you're trying to show all 3,000 records on the screen at once then yes, this is going to be a bit slow no matter how you code it. Instead of showing all records, you need to add pagination. You can start by using the LIMIT syntax of MySQL to select only 10 or 50 or whatever records at a time.

Comment: Ping Thanks for your suggestions !